# Using Van Selst and Jolicoeur formula for outlier elimination

Tags: outliers, bias

I would like to know which outlier elimination formula you would choose from (non-recursive or Van Selst and Jolicoeur) if you had two samples of 20 people each and if you wanted to compare their response times. An article by Van Selst and Jolicoeur mentions that a non-recursive method will be biased if the sample is less than 20 people (and from a non-normal distribution).

My questions are:

1. Does the sample size (20 people) matter if the sample sizes are equal for deciding which method to use?
2. Should I rather look at global sample size (i.e. 40 people)?
3. Should I look only at whether sample sizes are equal or not?

My thoughts are that both matter (comparative sample sizes and sample size by itself) when deciding on the type of outlier elimination method to use. For example, if I had two groups of 15 people each or one group with 25 and the other with 35, I would use the Van Selst-Jolicoeur method, but if I had two groups of 20 people each, then it would be fine to use the non-recursive method since there is at least 20 observations in each group.

The above question is based on a hypothetical scenario. Sometimes trimming means is necessary – my question is specific to what should be done given the above context (sample sizes) once the decision to trim has been taken.

Comment: I believe most (responsible) statisticians would be reluctant to recommend any procedure to eliminate data from your sample.  They would want to know why you are trying to do this, how such "outliers" might arise, and what implications their elimination might have for your study.  Consider editing your post to provide this information.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the comment. I have added more information. I just need a general understanding of the difference between VJ versus non-recursive method.

Comment: your response times are lognormally distributed or exponentially distributed?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 the response times are non-normal / positively skewed - I don't have more information than that for the problem.

Comment: Have you seen this paper: Behavior Research Methods, 2006, 38 (2) 344-352 "An SPSS implementation of the nonrecursive outlier deletion procedure with shifting z score criterion (Van Selst & Jolicoeur, 1994)" GLENN L. THOMPSON
University of Ottawa.

Comment: @phdmba7of12  I haven't seen it before, but it looks really useful - I'm going to go through it and look through the references too for more info! Thank you so much for referring me to that article :)